# Chart JS - How to output JSON objects into PIE variant

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am pulling a JSON response into a ChartJS pie chart. Reading the docs it says that it needs to use datasets as:

```
datasets: [{
    data: [10, 20, 30]
}],
```

For my use case, the JSON is pulling in as:

```
{
    "action": "data_link_referer",
    "result": {
        "url_ending": "0",
        "data": [{
            "label": "Link1",
            "clicks": 3
        }, {
            "label": "Link2",
            "clicks": 3
        }, {
            "label": "Link3",
            "clicks": 2
        }]
    }
}
```

Inside the chart function I am pulling out the [data]. I would like to set the `clicks` as the value.

```
function drawChartPie(jsonObj) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChartPie");
    var data = jsonObj["result"]["data"];

    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx,{
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: data,

            datasets: [{
                label: 'Referers',
                data: data,
            }]
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will convert your data into the right format for ChartJS

```
function formatData(response) {
    let newFormat = {
        datasets: [{
            data: []
        }],
        labels: []
    };
    response.result.data.forEach(item => {
        newFormat.datasets[0].data.push(item.clicks);
        newFormat.labels.push(item.label);
    });
    return newFormat;
}
```